# Not getting the expected return value of function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am a javascript newbie. I have a `9*9` grid for my sudoku game. The html is such that each box of the grid is an `input`element with id like `r1c4` where `1` is the **row** number and `4` is **column** number. I have half filled grid.I needed to store all the numbers in the grid in a `two` dimensional `array`.I have created the following function fo:

```
function getValues(){

    var grid = new Array();
    var colData = new Array();
    var targetId;

    for(var i=1;i<=9;i++)
    {
        for(var j=1;j<=9;j++)
        {   
            targetId = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
            colData[j-1] = document.querySelector('#'+targetId).value;

        }
        grid[i-1] = colData;
        console.log(grid[i-1]); // here logged correctly
    }
    return grid; // here returned wrong
}
```

The problem i am facing is that the returned array consists of only the last element repeated 9 times. I am logging the stored value every time by using `console.log(grid[i-1]);` and it is giving correct results.I am not getting it.

Regards.

Comment: Great answers on this page. Don't know who downvoted your question but I +1'd to balance it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid[i-1] = colData;
```

You are not copying `colData` to `grid[i-1]`, but simply making `grid[i-1]` a reference to `colData`. So, all the elements in your array are just references to the same object, `colData`.

To fix this problem, you need to create a new Array on every iteration. So, I would have done it like this

```
function getValues() {
    var grid = [], colData, targetId;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        colData = [];      // new Array on every iteration
        for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
            targetId = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
            colData.push(document.querySelector('#' + targetId).value);
        }
        grid.push(colData);
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new `colData` per iteration rather than using the same one each time.

```
for(var i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
  var colData = new Array();
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try either moving `colData = new Array()` (or better, `colData = [];`) inside the `i` for loop.

OR use `grid[i-1] = colData.slice(0);`.

Either way, you need to create a new array for each row, not just re-use the old one.

Answer (score 2):

You're using *the same* Array object for every single column, and just overwriting the values. You're pushing 9 references to that same array into your grid.

You need to move `var colData = new Array();` inside the loop so you're making a *new* Array for each column.